# not able to input date type data properly in my database

Tags: php, mysql

every thing is getting inputted correctly but date is being submitted into database like 0000-00-00. please help!! i tried to echo my date before posting it into dob and it coming out to be correct as inserted into the form. but when i check my database the dob columnsgets updates with a 0000-00-00.

here is the code:

```html
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($_POST);
echo "</pre>";}
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
//$salary = $_POST['salary'];
 $birthdate =  $_POST['year'] . '-' . $_POST['month']. '-' .$_POST['day'];
 echo $birthdate."<br>";

 
 
if(!empty($username)){
 if(!empty($password)){
  if(!empty($birthdate)){
  $servername = "localhost";
$usernamei = "root";
$passwordi = "password";
$databasei = "regis";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $usernamei, $passwordi, $databasei);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
else {
  echo $birthdate;
 $sql = "INSERT INTO iocl (user_name, password,dob)
 values ('$username','$password','$birthdate')";
 if($conn->query($sql)){
  echo "new record is inserted sucess";
 }
 else{
  echo "error: ".$sql."<br>".$conn->error;
 }
 $conn->close();
}}}}
 
    ?>
```

Comment: what is the type or the date field in your database?

Comment: Try `$birthdate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($birthdate))`. At line 8.

Comment: which type of `dob`  in database?

Comment: thanks but my code is also correct! XD 
didnt see the database properly